# How could a disabled UIButton trigger another event?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton, click

Well, I want to give a warning when users try to click a DISABLED UIButton.

How can I catch the event of a disabled button being clicked?

Comment: Tint the button or colour it so that it looks disabled, but fires off a method containing your warning to the user.

Comment: @Luke but I don't want the event to be triggered. Anyway to prevent this?

Comment: A button that is DISABLED is one that (by definition) is not enabled and therefore is not able to respond to events.  Why would you want to display a warning?  The fact that the button is disabled should be a visual cue to the user that nothing will happen if it is clicked.

Comment: @NickBull I have two buttons - Settings and Start, the Start is disabled until the settings are done. If users clicked the Start without clicking Settings first, the program will warn them to click Settings.

Comment: If they have to click the settings first, then why not hide the start button until after they have clicked the settings button? Having a button do something when it is clicked and it is disabled would lead to very confusing user experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not saying it's good design (I agree with the commenters who say that a tap on a disabled button shouldn't do anything), but you could attach a UITapGestureRecognizer to the parent view, and when the gesture comes in, check to see if the tap is within the bounds of the disabled view.

Taps on the disabled button will fire a UITapGestureRecognizer that's attached to the button's superview.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewTapped:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

and then in viewTapped

```
- (void)viewTapped:(id)sender {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
    CGPoint pt = [recognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.testButton];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.testButton.bounds, pt)) {
        NSLog(@"Disabled button tapped");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think Nick Bull is right, so I hide the button instead of disabling it

Comment: It should be UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewTapped:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];. Note the : on viewTapped. This solution makes sense to me, because I disable the button to get the grey shadow, but I want to reenable it after clicking, like a checkbox, with a checked and unchecked